# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in

Tags: php, syntax-error

Trying to run this single line of code and getting a syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO ...from what I can tell by searching it must have something to do with mis-use of { or ' maybe?  I have numerous combinations to no avail?  Any ideas?

```
echo(shell_exec('php -q /feeds/sancap/vrets/run_interactive_job.php /feeds/sancap/vrets/batch_control_files/Land'));
```

Comment: Any clue as to the contents of `/feeds/sancap/vrets/run_interactive_job.php`?

Comment: I have run your code but does not get any error

Comment: You will need to post the previous line(s), the error is not in the one you posted.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't terminate/close the previous statement properly.